# How to create a electric gate which can move from Point A to B

Tags: digital-logic, switches

I wanted to create an electric strip which will move from Point A to B and on discharge i.e 0 volt it will move to its original position.Like ,

[image: Base Position A and second position B]

The distance between point A and B would be small less than 1 cm , i tried with making a small electromagnet by simply charging the two ends of small copper
coil with 9v battery, but the force generated by it was small and i was not able to pull coil.

I can increase the number of windings or try with 12v battery but i don't think it would be of much use .Can anyone please suggest better approach

Comment: There is a lot of information missing to answer that question, like size, force needed, how fast the device must react, if low energy usage is needed, ...
Maybe you tell us what the actual application will be.

Comment: @0x6d64 : Yeah i will update the question

Comment: Electromagnets are seldom a good solution to this sort of need unless angle is small and force needed small. A motor and some wort of gearing is usually better.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : Actually the space i want to utilize is very small so i have dropped the plan of stepper motor use

Comment: @0x6d64 : I have updated the question :)

Comment: A motor and two position switches.

Comment: There are very small servo motors used for RC airplanes maybe one will fit your needs